# Which actions will consume time?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-gx-beginning-of-destiny

So just like the title says, which actions will consume time? I noticed that dueling people doesn't seem to consume any time on clock so I'm just wondering what does?

Comment: Does the time even pass at all? :P

Comment: @Kevin Well it should. Because there are specific events you have to go to at certain times. Like 7:00 AM is for breakfest, at 8:00 AM you have to go to class, etc.